# Access Domino Console on Windows from command line/remotely through putty?

Tags: ibm-domino

I have a Domino server running on a Windows server. Right now we are opening the Domino console GUI to enter and execute various commands.

I would like to automate and schedule some of these commands and possibly run them from a remote host as well. What are my options here? Would it be possible to use Putty or something similar to connect to the console and run commands? If not, can I run the commands from Windows commandline, without opening the Domino console?

Answer (score 1):

If your server starts with the java controller (command line -jc -c), then this controller listenes on port 2050 for remote commands. 
Unfortunately I do not know the specification of that interface, but probably googling might get you some answer.

But you can run any domino command by calling the nserver.exe from the domino- directory with a `-c` parameter.

For example to run a `show tasks` on the console you simple run the command `nserver.exe -c "show tasks"`.

Some commands allow to redirect the output to a file using `> path\file.txt`, but not all. To get the result from the rest of the commands, you need to check `IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT\console.log` in the domino data directory, if console logging is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I also want the same functionality to execute such commands from my workstation to view my lotus domino stats. 
this doesnt returns any thing if i execute it on lotus domino dos CMD. (in  lotus directory)

```
nserver.exe -c "show tasks"
```